# Angular App Url always saying 404 on refresh after deploy on IIS

Tags: angular, angular-routing

I deployed an application developed using angular 6 on IIS of windows server. 
Now I am facing one issue that on navigating the app if I am refreshing the page then it says **404 - File or directory not found.**
I looked at the posts related to this issue and tried to apply fix. but no luck. 
I do not want to use # with my urls. I just want to use urls simply like http://example.xyz.com/detail/12

If I am using # then its fine but I don't want to use #.

I tried to add a web.config as well, but no luck. Can any one help here how to fix this issue so that on refresh same page can be opened that I want to reload.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>

<system.webServer>
  <rewrite>
    <rules>
      <rule name="Angular Routes" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url=".*" />
        <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
          <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
          <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
        </conditions>
        <action type="Rewrite" url="./index.html" />
      </rule>
    </rules>
  </rewrite>
</system.webServer>

</configuration>
```

Comment: You should configure iis to route to index.html on unknown urls, since it thinks your angular route is a folder on server, and returns 404 since in reality there is no such folder

Comment: how it can be done? plz explain. as index.html already there in default documents in IIS

Comment: I am not iis master but like this i guess https://stackoverflow.com/a/43787391/6528560

Comment: yes its works 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43785928/angular-2-hosted-on-iis-http-error-404/43787391#43787391

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Follow this link to fix this issue
[Angular 2 Hosted on IIS: HTTP Error 404](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43785928/angular-2-hosted-on-iis-http-error-404/43787391#43787391)
or just

**Step 1: Install [IIS URL Rewrite](https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite) Module**

**Step 2: Add a rewrite rule to web.config**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <configuration>
      <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
          <rules>
            <rule name="AngularJS Routes" stopProcessing="true">
              <match url=".*" />
              <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />   
              </conditions>
              <action type="Rewrite" url="/" />
            </rule>
          </rules>
        </rewrite>
      </system.webServer>
    </configuration>
```

Comment: The above works even on Azure hosting, just need to add web.config file in "wwwroot" directory,
Default web.config file will not available in on angular build --prod,
So manually we need to add the web.config file

Comment: Hey I tried your weboconfig but always returns `Failed to load module script: Expected a JavaScript module script but the server responded with a MIME type of "text/html". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.`