# how to remove 404 error while refreshing SPA of Angular 8 without hash(#) routing?

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm using Angular 8 in my single page application project. When I upload my published code in IIS server and I don't use hash(#) in routing, It will get 404 error while I'm refreshing the page. Please help me out for this. Is there any solution to remove this error without using hash(#) in routing? because I want to make my URL SEO friendly.

Comment: You should add rewrite rules to `web.config` file, refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43785928/angular-2-hosted-on-iis-http-error-404

Comment: I added these rules in my web.config file but it didn't remove the hash(#) 
<rules><rule name="Rewrite rule1 for url rewrite"><match url=".*" /><conditions>
             <add input="{url rewrite:{REQUEST_URI}}" pattern="(.+)" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="{C:1}" appendQueryString="false" />
                </rule>
                <rule name="remove hash" patternSyntax="ExactMatch">
                    <match url="recipe" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="home" />
                </rule>
            </rules>

Comment: If you want to deploy just an angular app, you can simple create an express app and serve angular dist to it. Express will take care of routing, you won't get 404.

Comment: thanks but I didn't get what exactly you are saying. can you please explain me how to create express app for angular ?

Comment: For remove (#) from url you have to use `RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { useHash: false })` in `app.module.ts` file under `imports` section. Also refer this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53612218/angular-app-url-always-saying-404-on-refresh-after-deploy-on-iis

Comment: @hrdkisback - Thanks. I set useHash: false in appModule.ts file and also changed route in web.config file but still I get an error of 404.

Comment: Can you provide `URL` of application?

Answer (score 0):

You are getting a 404 because there is no HTML in path you have requested on your hosting server. It is needed for SPA to set up a redirection to index.html. Angular then will bootstrap application and redirect to proper view.

This is how to set it up in the most common web servers.

- Apache [Htaccess rule to redirect domain to index.html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1911417/htaccess-rule-to-redirect-domain-to-index-html)
- IIS [Angular 2 Hosted on IIS: HTTP Error 404](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43785928/angular-2-hosted-on-iis-http-error-404)
- Nginx [How to redirect all Angular request to index.html in Nginx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35038155/how-to-redirect-all-angular-request-to-index-html-in-nginx)

Comment: I added these rules in my web.config file but it didn't remove the hash(#) 
<rules><rule name="Rewrite rule1 for url rewrite"><match url=".*" /><conditions>
             <add input="{url rewrite:{REQUEST_URI}}" pattern="(.+)" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="{C:1}" appendQueryString="false" />
                </rule>
                <rule name="remove hash" patternSyntax="ExactMatch">
                    <match url="recipe" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="home" />
                </rule>
            </rules>