# On Reload Angular7 application getting 404 after deployment

Tags: javascript, angular, nginx

Removed # from the URL
before using "{provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: HashLocationStrategy}"
this in appModule file After Removing this getting 404 and

https://example.com/dashboard//home in logs i saw one extra '/' is getting added from NGINX

After NGINX Changes

```
 location / {
    alias /usr/share/nginx/html/;
         try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
          try_files $uri $uri/ = 404;
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html =404;
  }
```

tried these below 2 solution

[Angular 2 Hosted on IIS: HTTP Error 404](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43785928/angular-2-hosted-on-iis-http-error-404)

[Angular deployment - 404 on page Refresh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45072185/angular-deployment-404-on-page-refresh)

Comment: Try this: `root /usr/share/nginx/html; index index.html; location / { try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html; }`

Comment: Which solution did you try? Please state what exactly you tried. Also: https://angular.io/guide/deployment#routed-apps-must-fallback-to-indexhtml

Comment: @penleychan tried changing the NGINX config , but not sure after deploying y its giving 404 , before was using # in URL and now removed after that started getting this.

Comment: @penleychan https://angular.io/guide/deployment#routed-apps-must-fallback-to-indexhtml tried this as well

Answer (score 0):

```
location / {
    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    try_files $uri /index.html =404;
}
```

added this to NGINX and worked for me

Thanks :)