# reload or refresh page return 404 in IIS web hosting

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, web, redirect, iis

I create a website with angular 13 and ASP.core but I can't use window.location.reload(); or refresh my page return  HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found
The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.

[image]

Comment: ABCs for Angular developers, https://angular.io/guide/deployment#routed-apps-must-fall-back-to-indexhtml

Comment: The reason for this problem is that Angular controls routing by itself. If you deploy to IIS, you need to configure route rewriting, more information you can refer to this link: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43785928/angular-2-hosted-on-iis-http-error-404](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43785928/angular-2-hosted-on-iis-http-error-404).

Comment: in my local server the routing is working well with IIS but i have problem with web hosting routing